# How to choose max value between every tow records in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, view, filter

My table in Sqlite have:

```
ID  studentID  Name   Lesson TryNo   Degree           
1      1       John     a1     1       23
2      1       John     a1     2       66
3      1       John     b1     1       55
4      1       John     b1     2       null
5      1       John     c1     1       45
6      1       John     c1     2       50
7      2       Sara     a1     1       88
8      2       Sara     a1     2       null
9      2       Sara     b1     1       45
10     2       Sara     b1     2       32
11     2       Sara     c1     1       null
12     2       Sara     c1     2       55
```

Students like john and Sara have three lessons, and if they fail in the first try, they will make second try for the same lesson.
My question, I like to create new view which contain the best degree in each lesson instead of two degrees, so the new view should show these values:

```
ID  studentID  Name   Lesson TryNo   Degree           

2      1       John     a1     2       66
3      1       John     b1     1       55
6      1       John     c1     2       50

7      2       Sara     a1     1       88
9      2       Sara     b1     1       45
12     2       Sara     c1     2       55
```

I try to do it since 2 days without result, any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With SQLite 3.7.11 or later, simply combine GROUP BY and MAX:

```
SELECT ID, studentID, Name, Lesson, TryNo, MAX(Degree) AS Degree
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY studentID, Name, Lesson
```

In earlier SQLite versions, the columns `ID` and `TryNo` are not guaranteed to get their values from the same record that matches the `MAX` (and most other databases will error out).
In that case, you have to look up the largest degree for each unique student/lesson combination, and use that to filter out the other records:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE ID = (SELECT ID
            FROM MyTable AS T2
            WHERE T2.studentID = MyTable.studentID
              AND T2.Lesson    = MyTable.Lesson
            ORDER BY Degree DESC
            LIMIT 1)
```